# When should i save presistent file - android

Tags: android

Im building a app using java, it contains 3 activities that supose to share data with each other.
The data is also suposed to be preserved after the user exits the app and accsseiable the next time he runs it.

To do that i used a singletone object to store the data while the app is runing and i wanted to save the data on the users phone using a text file.
The text file will contain that same singletone using json so i can restore it and save it easly.

Inoreder to save that text file I used input/outputFile and it actualy works fine.

The problem I have is that I cant decide where to save a copy of this singetone object.
for now I overided the onStop method in each activity and called the method that saves that object instance to that text file, but i think it will make the app realy slow when ill have more data.

Do you have any suggestions how to improve that solution?

Comment: About how much data are you talking? And why not using shared preferences?

Comment: It dependes on the users usage, I save scan logs  that needs to be acessiable throughout the app so I can build some graphs with them.
I used a singletone to hold them all togather and im actually saving that singletone.

Comment: I had two questions. You did not answer one of them.